# Is it possible to convert img src to base64 in js without xhr?

Tags: javascript, html, webview, xmlhttprequest, jspdf

For some reason,I can't use any xhr request in my webview,so all the src of img can be loaded when I open the html, but if I want to save them to a pdf using something like jsPDF, all the img will be missing because of xhr request fail.So I want to ask is there any way to convert img src to base64 after page loaded without xhr request? And after page loaded,I think the images are already downloaded, so is it possible to find it locally and convert to base64 then set them back to src?

Comment: "For some reason,I can't use any xhr request in my webview" — **What reason?**. Anything that prevents you using XMLHttpRequest is likely to prevent a lot of other solutions from working!

Comment: Yes, because my html have to run in an app named wechat, in it's webview, and this app prevents XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe use canvas to change srcs to base64?

```
 const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    
    images.forEach(img => {
      img.onload = function() {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        img.setAttribute("src", dataURL);
      };
    });
```